# Map "undefined" index to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we have an Array like so:

```
var example = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

We know that we can access an index of 0-4:

```
example[0] == "a"
example[1] == "b"
example[2] == "c"
example[3] == "d"
example[4] == "e"
```

However, we also want to map an `undefined` index. For example:

```
example[0] == example[5] == example[10] == example[15] == example[20] == "a"
example[1] == example[6] == example[11] == example[16] == example[21] == "b"
example[2] == example[7] == example[12] == example[17] == example[22] == "c"
example[3] == example[8] == example[13] == example[18] == example[23] == "d"
example[4] == example[9] == example[14] == example[19] == example[24] == "e"
```

Though it may be simple, the math is simply escaping my mind. Keep in mind the `example.length` is not fixed and may be different at times. How would one go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to want to use the [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) :

```
example[i%example.length]
```

Comment: Well that was quick! I forgot about the modulo.